# class cast exception in selenium rc

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

i am trying to get first 10 urls from google search and trying to record them onto a file using selenium rc my code is as follows

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;


public class GoogleSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        {
            int count = 0, sel_count=0, code_google_count=0;
            String link,sel_text="seleniumhq.org",code_google_text="code.google.com";
            List<WebElement> results;
            Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://www.google.co.in");
            selenium.start();
            selenium.open("/");
            selenium.type("q", "selenium");
            selenium.click("btnG");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Collection<WebElement> searchResults = ((WebElement) selenium).findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li/div/h3/a"));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
            for (WebElement webElement : searchResults) 
            {
                link = webElement.getAttribute("href");
                    out.println(link);
        }
            out.close();            
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

but when i try this i got an error like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

can any one tell me how to proceed as per this error

Comment: Consider upgrading to WebDriver. RC has been discontinued for quite some time now.

Comment: @SiKing : ok i will upgrade but is there a solution for this or not???

Comment: The answer from @Richard below, specifically "not entirely certain what you're attempting here", can you explain that. If not, can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: @SiKing : i said it na, ok listen i want to open google , type selenium (or any other word) , wait until the page load and then grab first 10 URL's available in that page

Comment: The code that @Richard posted should work. If not, you need to post additional information. See [Ask] for some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you're attempting here:

```
Collection<WebElement> searchResults = ((WebElement) selenium).findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li/div/h3/a"));
```

You're attempting to cast an object of type `WebDriver` to an object of type `WebElement`.  This should not be necessary.

This should work for you:

```
List<WebElement> searchResults = selenium.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li/div/h3/a"));
```

As has been pointed out, you're actually using `DefaultSelenium`, and then trying to call a `WebDriver` method against it.

Comment: ok but when i copied the code as u given then also it is throwing the same error